# Validate no permitted URLS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I need users NOT to be able to introduce a URL in an input.

What is the best way to do this? Maybe a Regular Expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if really the best code, but could try something like this:

```
validates :does_not_contain_url


private

def does_not_contain_url
  text_field.split(/\s/).each do |part|
    begin
      uri = URI.parse(part)
      self.errors.add :text_field, "No URLS allowed" if %w(http https).include?(uri.scheme)
    rescue URI::BadURIError
      self.errors.add :text_field, "No URLS allowed"
    end
  end

end
```